# School wifi partially blocks UDP server

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, udp, dgrams

I am making a multiplayer game that is UDP with node.js (dgram for UDP) and unity as the client (uses c#'s sockets). I originally had a web-socket server, but remade it to be UDP for more competitive response times.

It works perfectly at my house and between my and my friends, but when I try it at school it doesn't work (both LAN and WAN). With non-local hosting nothing works (expected because my school has a whitelist), but with LAN (not localhost) The client sends and initial join packet (exactly the same way of sending as everything else) but then just doesn't send any more packets. My server logs the join message but then the client gets timed out from not sending any more messages after that.

Additionally, the client freezes during the second message and has to be shut down from task manager, which gives me the idea that it's message is being blocked over the network.

Is there a way around my school wifi blocking my server messages, and if there isn't what should I ask my school's tech person for (probably won't work but worth a shot)

Thanks in advance (:

Comment: Solutions here depend upon what exactly is being blocked.  If traffic is being blocked based on IP/DNS, then you need to get added to the school whitelist.  If UDP packets are being blocked because they are not part of a known service, then you'd have to talk to the school IT folks (whoever manages their security) about possible solutions.  You could also run some UDP tests and if they don't work, then fall back to the webSocket mechanism on a per connection basis.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is nothing you can do to solve certain situations like this by bypassing alone.
If your school remotely controls what protocols (TCP, UDP) that is allowed or blocked, it is better and the right thing to ask them to lift the ban up for traffic between UDP connections.

Also, the firewall can be the main one to blame. By default, many firewalls block UDP traffic because essentially, it is an **unsolicited network traffic** and may be used to do malicious exploitation since it doesn't care whether or not it has the server's permission to communicated in between and it can't do it doesn't support [ACK](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/what-is-an-ack-flood/#:%7E:text=ACK%20is%20short%20for%20%22acknowledgement.%22%20An%20ACK%20packet,with%20the%20%22ACK%22%20flag%20set%20in%20the%20header) (Can even cause DDOS in that manner).

More information and references about UDP: [Link](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/glossary/user-datagram-protocol-udp/#:%7E:text=UDP%20%E2%80%98risks%E2%80%99%20like%20packet%20loss%20are%20not%20a,first%20getting%20that%20server%E2%80%99s%20permission%20to%20begin%20communication.)

However it is more of an overstatement but know that firewall in general do block all incoming traffics by default. TCP is usually accepted, and maybe your school blocked all UDP connections because of the details said above.